# What is the difference between contrib/lisp and lisp?

Tags: directories

I have both of these folders for my load paths, what is the difference?

`~/.emacs.d/contrib/lisp/` vs `~/.emacs.d/lisp/`

What should I use one versus the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Emacs there's no difference between these.  In fact these aren't even Emacs' paths.  Emacs enforces no structure upon `~/.emacs.d/`; everything that's in there is a matter of your personal configuration.  In other words, if you're having these paths on `load-path` then only because *your* configuration added them.

Hence, the only one who can tell the difference between these, is you :)  And if you don't know, chances are that you don't actually need both :)